# Use AWS Websocket Api with Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns, amazon-elasticache

I want to use the Amazon Websocket Api to connect clients with my backend service ( docker container ) . I want to use a pub/sub system and I am asking me if it would be possible to connect a websocket connection directly to a SNS topic?

Does someone have a tutorial for using Aws Websocket Api / Sns or Elastic Cache?

Thanks